# How do I access a feature layer's "displayField" from a REST SOE?

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-server, arcgis-10.2, server-object-extension

Understanding I can't use the 'ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.IFeatureLayer' interface, how can I get to a Feature Layer's "displayField" from a REST server object extension using arcobjects C#?

```
FeatureLayer.DisplayField
```

Answer (score 1):

Black thumb.

```
IMapServer3 mapServer = (IMapServer3)serverObjectHelper.ServerObject;
string mapName = mapServer.DefaultMapName;
IMapLayerInfos layerInfos = mapServer.GetServerInfo(mapName).MapLayerInfos;
...

string displayField = layerInfos.get_Element(i).DisplayField;
```